# Creating a procedure doesn't work in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried plenty of codes but this does not seem to work, I'm using VScode, does it has something to do with it ?. Either way here are all the codes I've tried:

```
CREATE procedure testProcedure()
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM order_id
END;
```

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure testProcedure()
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM order_id
END
DELIMITER $$
```

```
CREATE procedure testProcedure()
AS
    SELECT * FROM order_id
GO;
```

All of them would throw a syntax error at the `DELIMTER $$`, `BEGIN`, or `AS`

If I omit the parenthesis in `testProcedure` in the `BEGIN ... END` , it will throw this error:

[image]

Here's the version of MySQL:

[image]

*To mods: this is not a duplicate as I searched and tried pretty much everything but they did not work for me, thanks.

Comment: MySQL has a dedicated IDE called Workbench and can be downloaded for the MySQL site. Perhaps use this rather than VSCode.

Comment: I have also tried in the Workbench as well, but the errors still persist

Comment: I tried it and it throws this error: ER_PARSE_ERROR, error in SQL syntax; ... for the right syntax near '' at line 4

Comment: @Shadow because you need the semicolon after order_id . This `CREATE procedure testProcedure()
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM order_id ;
END`

Comment: Thank you!!! this worked beautifully for me